# ¿Cómo mostrar los 5 registros más repetidos en un Array?

Tags: c++, array

Tengo dos archivos de texto que tienen registros de clientes  y tarjetas

Hasta el momento tengo,

1. Un registro por cada veces que un clientes esta registrado en el archivo tarjeta  en el vector

Ahora necesito saber, los 5 clientes que más se repiten en el vector

Agradezco su apoyo y comparto el código utilizado para ese método.

```c++
void  MostrarUsuariosTarjetas()//muestra todos los datos de la tarjeta
{
     stCliente mostrarCliente; //estructura cliente
     stTarjeta mostrarTarjeta; //estructura tarjetas


     fstream archivoTarjeta("DATOS//tarjetas.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
     fstream archivoCliente("DATOS//clientes.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

     if(archivoTarjeta.fail())
        cerr << "Error al abrir tarjetas.txt" << endl;
    if(archivoCliente.fail())
        cerr << "Error al abrir clientes.txt" << endl;

     else
    {
        //cuento cantidad de clientes
    int countTarjetas = 0;
        while(!archivoTarjeta.eof())
        {
            archivoTarjeta.read((char*)&mostrarTarjeta,sizeof(stTarjeta));
            if(!archivo.eof())
             {countTarjetas++}
        }       
        //para llevar un tope
        char charClientes[countTarjetas];
        bool dec = true;
        int countClientesEncontrados = 0;
         while(!archivo.eof())
             {
                 archivoTarjeta.read((char*)&mostrarTarjeta,sizeof(stTarjeta));

                if(!archivoTarjeta.eof())
                 {  
                    if(dec){charClientes[countClientesEncontrados] = mostrarTarjeta.nombre; dec = false;}
                    else
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i <countTarjetas ; i++ )
                        {
                            if(charClientes[i] == mostrarTarjeta.nombre)
                            {
                                charClientes[countClientesEncontrados] = mostrarTarjeta.nombre;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                 }

                 countClientesEncontrados++;
             }

        //Mostrar los 5 clientes mas repetidos
        ///
        ///
        ///
            cout << "\n\n\n" ;
    }   
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    archivoTarjeta.close();
    archivoCliente.close();

 }
```

Me pueden apoyar, anticipadas gracias....

Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: ¿Y no has intentado nada hasta la fecha para obtener el resultado?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `stCliente` y `stTarjeta`? ¿Qué debe ser tenido en cuenta para considerar que dos instancias de `stCliente` o `stTarjeta` son iguales? ¿El código te compila? Por lo que veo estás usando [FTV](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+vla) y eso debería hacer fallar la compilación.

Comment: En la de **stTarjeta** solo me interesa su propiedad nombre que es el **ID** del cliente, ya que necesito sacar los clientes  que más movimientos hacen con tarjetas. La de **stCliente** la usaré para algo más. Si tenés razón pueden haber errores de compilación esos los veo después, ahorita necesito apoyo en cuanto al al algoritmo. Gracias, seguiré intentando.

Answer (score 1):

Ayudandote con el algoritmo, no se muy bien que datos tienen las estructuras. Pero creo que esto te puede servir.

Asumiendo que el archivo clientes contiene el id de todos los clientes y asumiendo que el archivo tarjeta contiene todos los registros hechos con cualquier tarjeta.

Algoritmo.

Paso 1: leer los 2 archivos.

Paso 2: por cada cliente buscar y contar y almacenar su actividad con una tarjeta.

Paso 3: Ordenar la data almacenada en el paso 2 de manera descendente.

Paso 4: Obtener los 5 primeros elementos de la data ordenada en el paso 3.

En pseudocodigo deberas tener algo como esto:

```
Arreglo de Cliente clientes = leerArchivo("Nombre archivo clientes")
Arreglo de Tarjeta tarjetas = leerArchivo("Nombre de archivo tarjetas")

para i = 0 donde i < clientes.tam hacer{
   Cliente cliente = clientes[i];
   para j = 0 donde j < tarjetas.tam hacer{ 
       Tarjeta tarjeta = tarjetas[j];
       if tarjeta.idDueño == cliente.id{
          cliente[i].transaccionesRealizadas += 1
       }
   }
}

Arreglo de Clientes clientesSort = ordenarDecendente(clientes)


   para i = 0 donde i < 5 hacer{
    // nombre del cliente
     print(clientesSort[i].nombre)
    // numero de transacciones
    print(clientesSort[i].transaccionesRealizadas)
  }
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.